# JTextPane - how to style selected text

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am looking for the most simple way to control JTextPane (its inner text) font color and font size within selected text only.

I know I must look at StyledDocument but its snippets show the JMenu action listener tricks but not JButton :(

I couldn't find code snippets which could show how to change **selected text** style by JButton clicked (the actionPerformed(...) method) etc :(

I mean something in this direction

- A) I have a text in JTextPane lets say "My home is to turn into
  borabora and this is..."
- B) Text "borabora" is selected in JTextPane
- C) JButton("size=16") was clicked
- D) Text "borabora" size becomes 16

I couldn't find this kind of snippets so I need your advice.

Any useful comment is appreciated

Comment: ActionListeners and JButtons have nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your actionPerformed method of the applicable jbutton you could run this. (modify as needed.)

```
String text = jTextPane.getSelectedText();
int cursorPosition = jTextPane.getCaretPosition();

StyleContext context = new StyleContext();
Style style;

jTextPane.replaceSelection("");

style = context.addStyle("mystyle", null);
style.addAttribute(StyleConstants.FontSize, new Integer(16));
jTextPane.getStyledDocument().insertString(cursorPosition - text.length(), text, style);
```

Comment: Quite interesting thanks. As I can see it is always insertString in use here? So should I insert a modified text instead of the previous one? Is it the major strategy or there is another way?

Comment: I'm sure they are better ways. I currently replace the selected area with an empty string .. apply  a style as needed to the saved text and do an insert into the location of previously selected text.

Comment: Oh :) I see so there should be a replacement then? Ok I'll try in this direction and report my results as soon as possible :)

Comment: -1 for not reading the api doc (+0.2 for having a hunch of showing something ... suboptimal ;-)

Comment: Thanks. The snippet helped much :)

Answer (score 2):

> but its snippets show the JMenu action listener tricks but not JButton

You can add an Action to a JButton as well as well as a JMenu. For example:

```
Jbutton button = new JButton( new StyledEditorKit.FontSizeAction("16", 16) );
```

You would use Styles when you want to apply multiple properies at one time to a piece of text.

Comment: Action italicAction = new ItalicAction();
    italicAction.putValue(Action.NAME, "Italic");
    styleMenu.add(italicAction);

Comment: OK but how to listen to this action I mean Jbutton button = new JButton( new StyledEditorKit.FontSizeAction("16", 16) );
?

Comment: I already gave you the answer. Its one line of code. All you have to do is try it.

Comment: No, I mean how to use its actionPerformed() method then? And how to catch what text is selected to make its size as 16 or it is some auto thing?

Comment: Its the same as any editor. You select the text first, then you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @scartag answer and the comment about the API (from @kleopatra), I have found another way to do it.

```
StyleContext context = new StyleContext();
Style style = context.addStyle("mystyle", null);
style.addAttribute(StyleConstants.FontSize, new Integer(16));;
jTextPane.setCharacterAttributes(style , true);
```

The method `setCharacterAttributes(style, replace)` changes the style of the selected text so you don't need to remove it and add again with a new style. And more, the boolean replace indicates if the style replaces the old style (`true`) or if is added to the old style (`false`).